# How to get sum of sales for every hover in day by MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to get sum of every hover sales in a day.
Date Fotomat in my DB is (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm) 
I am having table as

[image]

I need something like this:
[image]

Comment: did you find the answer below useful? If it was useful, can you mark it as accepted to put closure to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It might be valuable for you to create a table that holds hours like so:

```
create table hours (hr int primary key);

insert into hours values
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24);
```

Let's assume your table looks like this in **MySQL**:

```
create table test (
    sale_no int auto_increment primary key,
    entry_date timestamp,
    sales_done int
);
```

Or if it was **SQL Server**:

```
create table test (
    sale_no int identity primary key,
    entry_date datetime,
    sales_done int
);
```

**Data looks like this:**

```
insert into test (entry_date, sales_done) values 
('2017-03-06 01:27:00', 5), ('2017-03-06 01:26:00', 7),
('2017-03-06 02:25:00', 7), ('2017-03-06 02:23:00', 6),
('2017-03-06 02:18:00', 5), ('2017-03-06 02:07:00', 4),
('2017-03-06 03:26:00', 5), ('2017-03-06 03:25:00', 7),
('2017-03-06 04:23:00', 7), ('2017-03-06 04:18:00', 8);
```

**Query you'd write in MySQL is:**

```
select h.hr, coalesce(t.count, 0) as count 
from hours h
left join (
    select hour(entry_date) as hr, sum(sales_done) as count
    from test
    group by hour(entry_date)
) t on t.hr = h.hr
order by h.hr;
```

**Query you'd write in SQL Server:**

```
select h.hr, coalesce(t.count, 0) as count 
from hours h
left join (
    select datepart(hour, entry_date) as hr, sum(sales_done) as count
    from test
    group by datepart(hour, entry_date)
) t on t.hr = h.hr
order by h.hr;
```

**Result:**

```
+----+-------+
| hr | count |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    12 |
|  2 |    22 |
|  3 |    12 |
|  4 |    15 |
|  5 |     0 |
| .. |    .. |
| 24 |     0 |
+----+-------+
```

MySQL Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/943db3/1

SQL Server Example: http://rextester.com/QQK91065